# this.props.history.push('/') IS NOT WORKING in CLASS Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

Please help me to resolve the issue of this.props.history.push('/') IS NOT WORKING in CLASS Component. As we do not have any scope of using history anymore. Unable to implement navigate.
Please do help. Same issue with props.location.state.contact.

```
**const { name, email } = props.location.state.contact;**
```

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../assets/css/AddContact.css";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";

class AddContact extends Component {
  state = {
    id: uuid(),
    name: "",
    email: "",
  };

 
  add = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.name === "" || this.state.email === "") {
      alert("All fields are required!");
      return;
    }
    this.props.addContactHandler(this.state);
    this.setState({ name: "", email: "" });
    this.props.history.push("/");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="contactForm">
        <h2 className="contactForm__title">Add Contact</h2>
        <div className="contactForm__form">
          <form action="/" method="post" onSubmit={this.add}>
            <div className="contactForm__nameField">
              <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
              <br />
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter your name"
                name="name"
                id="name"
                value={this.state.name}
                onChange={(e) => this.setState({ name: e.target.value })}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="contactForm__emailField">
              <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
              <br />
              <input
                type="email"
                placeholder="Enter your email"
                name="email"
                id="email"
                value={this.state.email}
                onChange={(e) => this.setState({ email: e.target.value })}
              />
            </div>
            <button className="contactForm__button">Add</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AddContact;
```

I tried out from all of my references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [withRouter](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) Higher Order Component provided with the React Router library in order to get access to those props (`history` and `location` automatically).

So just import that, and change your export to

```
export default withRouter(AddContact);
```

[Note that this assumes you are using React Router v5 or before - there is no `withRouter` in v6 which is the latest version. But your use of a class component implies that you are using an earlier version - v6 only works well if you use function components, as `withRouter` has been replaced with Hooks.]